# Pagination very heavy SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql, entity-framework-core

I am trying to improve performance of some report in my system. Application is written in .NET Core 3.0, I am using EF-Core as ORM Framework and PostgreSQL as database. This report returns thousands of records and in some view it is presented to user. The results are paginated, ordered by some selected column (like start_time or agent_name etc.).

This result is calculated from heavy query (one execution takes about 10 seconds). To implement pagination, we need to calculate results for one page and total count. I can see 2 approaches how to solve this problem. Both of them have some disadvantages.

In current solution I am downloading full report, and then I am sorting it and slicing one page in memory. Advantage of this solution is that data is fetched from database only once. Disadvantage - we load thousands of record, but in fact we need only one page (50 records).

Other approach which I can see is slice records in DB (using LIMIT and OFFSET operators). I will fetch only on page of data, but I don't have count of all records, so I need to make second query with same query parameters which returns count of all records.

What do you think about this problem? Which approach is in your opinion better? Maybe some other technique is best for this issue?

Comment: The second approach (backend pagination) requires a key on the result set. If you cannot identify a `UNIQUE` set of columns, then you can't go this way, and you'll be forced to use the first approach. Is this the case?

Comment: @TheImpaler I have a key on my result set, I don't have any problems with identification my rows.

Comment: My advice: forget about the total row count. You cannot get that without actually executing the complete query. Try to go with [keyset pagination](https://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset) if possible.

Comment: You are asking for an opinion.  But the best solution is probably to download the first page, display it, and then download the rest of the data while loading the page.

Comment: "we load thousands of record, but in fact we need only one page (50 records)."  How do you know you need only one page?  If you already know that no one will use the pagination, then why implement it?